# Hapi.js what is the use of a plugin callback?

Tags: express, plugins, routes, middleware, hapi.js

I am new to hapi.js coming from express.js I am trying to understand the difference (if there is) between the hapi.js pluging concept and the express.js middleware. In some examples and tutorials, I see a callback in the registration of a plugin. e.g:

```
// load one plugin
server.register(require('myplugin'), (err) => {

    if (err) {
        console.error('Failed to load plugin:', err);
    }

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/test',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
           reply('test passed');
        }
    });
});
```

So my question is: what is the use declaring a rest route in the callback of a plugin registration versus declaring this route outside?

And more generally I would like to know the difference between the execution of plugins in the hapi.js framework versus middleware in express.js ( In express.js middleware are executed one after another as the request is being processed, until the last middleware is called. Is it the same way in hapi.js?)

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

The order of plugin registration in hapi.js is not related to the request lifecycle. However, your plugins might need to be declared in a certain order, for dependencies issues, and if you need to run some code once the plugin is registered.

Here is an example requiring this callback:

```
server.register(require('hapi-auth-jwt'), err => {
 if (err) {
   console.log(err);
   return null;
 }
 server.auth.strategy('token', 'jwt', {

   key: process.env.JWT_SECRET,

   verifyOptions: {
     algorithms: ['HS256']
   }
 });
 server.register(/*other plugins*/)
}
```

Also remember that the plugin register function can be asynchronous (by calling **next()** whenever you want)

The architecture of hapi is very different from express. You can see it as blocks (plugins) instead of layers (middlewares). It's also "**configuration over code**" oriented.